# Entity Framework Cascade Delete

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have Table A and Table B on SQL Server.

Table B has an foreign key to Table A.

I want to cascade delete Table B itens when I delete a Table A item.

How to set this on SQL Server and on Entity Data Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the SQL server, set the `Delete Rule` in `INSERT and UPDATE specification` on the relationship property to `Cascade`.

Comment: Where? On the foreign key properties of this relationship? I had this doubt because it is not intuitive. It doesn't say wich end of the relationship it reffers. Thanks, man.

Comment: Yes. The cascade delete will apply when the "master" is deleted, deleting all the "children"

Answer (score 0):

Set CASCADE on the relationship in the Entity Model Designer...