# C# How to remove reference between two entities using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have models:

- Student = (... List CourseList);
- Course = (... List StudentList);

I added students to few different courses and using Entity Framework, I added everything to the database.

Please help me remove student from specific course using EF

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381689/delete-related-elements-in-1n-relation-and-not-only-inserts-null-in-the-foreign

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858491/entity-framework-remove-object-with-foreign-key-preserving-parent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It greatly helps to show your models and code for assistance. I'll take a stab based on your pseudo code:

```
var course = context.Courses.Include(c => c.Students)
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CourseID == selectedCourseId);

if (course != null)
{
    var studentToRemove = course.Students.SingleOrDefault(s => c.StudentID == selectedStudentId);
    if (studentToRemove != null)
    {
        course.Students.Remove(studentToRemove);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :)

And sorry for my bad explanation of my problem, i was on the phone and in a hurry, that will never happen again! :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit if you have configured a [one-to-many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) or a [many-to-many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

I think every `Student` can attend zero or more `Courses`, and every `Course` can be attended by zero or more `Students`: a many-to-many relation ship.

This is configured as follows:

```
class Student
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   // a Student attends zero or more courses:
   public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}
class Course
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   // a Course is attended by zero or more Students:
   public virtual ICollection<Student> Students{get; set;}
}
class MyDbContext : DbConter
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}
```

This is all. From this Entity Framework will know you want to design a many-to-many relationship. It will even create and fill the many-to-many junction table for you.

So now you've added some Students and Some Courses.
Suppose you want to remove a Student.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    Student studentToRemove = ... 
    // for example:
    Student studentToRemove = dbContext.Students
         .Where(student => student.Name == "John Doe")
         .FirstOrDefault();
    if (studentToRemove != null)
    {
        dbContext.Students.Remove(studentToRemove);
        dbConext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

That is all. Entity Framework will remove the `Student` from the `Students` table and automatically make sure that he can't be found on any of the `Courses` lists. You don't have to do some inner join. Entity Framework knows it is a many-to-many relationship and will do the correct inner join for you